# Graphics driver, muted whites and colors

Tags: windows, graphics

Upgraded Windows 7 graphics driver (out-of-the-box driver worked great except it had no OpenGL support).

Now that I've got the newer driver (Intel) installed, everything looks muted. Whites are not quite as white, colors are slightly muted, less rich/vibrant (desaturated?). Almost as if the LCD brightness had been turned down a notch. (In fact, that's what I thought had happened at first!)

Neither gamma, brightess, contrast or temperature seem to be able to bring it back to what it was. Is there something else I should check? LCD brightness is still set to 100%...

Comment: What monitor is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed `igfxpers.exe` and `igfxtray.exe` from auto-run, rebooted and the display seems normal again!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what monitor type you have, you might try changing the digital color format from `RGB` to `YCbCr444`. For some monitor types colors display better with the `YCbCr444` format.

(see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/361551/what-is-ycbcr444/361556))

Comment: Usually you can find it as an option in the driver settings (for nVidia, the nVidia Control Panel or for AMD the Catalyst Control Center). I'm not sure what Intel graphics options are though as I've never used them